# How to run test methods in specific order in JUnit4?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I want to execute test methods which are annotated by `@Test` in specific order.

For example:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test public void test1(){}
    @Test public void test2(){}
}
```

I want to ensure to run `test1()` before `test2()` each time I run `MyTest`, but I couldn't find annotation like `@Test(order=xx)`.

I think it's quite important feature for JUnit, if author of JUnit doesn't want the **order feature**, why?

Comment: They seem to me to be executed in the order they appear in the source file.

Comment: You should never write tests that need to be executed in a specified order. That's really bad practice. Every test should be able to run independent.

Comment: I think the tests, when run individually are run in the order they appear in the file but if run as part of a suite they tend to be run in alphabetical order.  I agree that tests should be independent but in my case I was testing that a cache is loaded once and then the same cache is called without loaded every other time after that until it is purged.  I made sure they were in the order I wanted them to run in, in the file, and then I named them test1, test2 to ensure they ran in the suite correctly.  It's not perfect but you could try it.

Comment: @EJP this was almost universally true of java pre 7. Pre 7, most JVMs did this, but it was never guaranteed. Java 7 JVMs can return the methods in a non-deterministic order.

Comment: @Apfelsaft so what are test suits useful for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649410/how-can-i-run-or-change-the-order-of-specific-test-methods-in-a-junit-test-cla

Comment: Work around. Remove @Test from you test cases, convert them as private functions, then crate a single test case, and call private functions in order.

Comment: Removing @Test from the test cases will mess up the JUnit report. By the way, enforcing a specific order is a bad practice for **Unit tests** but not necessarily a bad practice for **Integration tests**. The best choice (not ideal) is to annotate the class with `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`, keep the `@Test` annotation for all test methods and rename them alphabetically depending on the desired order of execution, e.g. `t1_firstTest()`, `t2_secondTest()`, etc.

Comment: @Apfelsaft - Please tell us why it is a bad idea to have tests execute in a specific order.

Comment: It's very easy to pontificate about how unit tests need to be independent, but there are still very good reasons for running tests in a specific order. In my case, I run three separate tests for each of 7 possible values of an input parameter. And for each possible value, I want to compare those three tests, so it's much easier to do this if they're grouped together in the output. It also helps me recognize patterns in the test failures. So thanks go to the people who actually answered the question.

Comment: People who say that is a bad practice probably never written tests or anything other than unit tests. Remember We will have test dependencies for integration tests or ui tests with selenium.

Comment: @Apfelsaft, it is not correct that every test should be independent nor is it inherently good practice for tests to be independent. In general, tests should be independent, but here's a case where order and dependency is a _great_ idea: I have tests that rely on Java GUI automation, which frequently fails when a system component (JDK, operating system, etc.) has been updated. So I have a test that tests basic ability to manipulate the GUI. I want this test run first so that I see as I view the test results that it failed. And in fact, I want its failure to halt the entire test suite.

Comment: Even for unit tests, a specific order might be necessary when certain aspects rely on a `ThreadLocal<AtomicInteger>` counter or similar that leaks into the assertions of necessary aspects.

Comment: Junit is really good at running unit tests and therefore in general tests should be randomized so you detect if one impacts another.  If you are running GUI tests, I recommend a different test tool that's better tailored to the task.  Integration tests can be tough, I've really wanted them ordered but those tended to be fragile and hard to maintain, It's worth the effort to force yourself to write them independently.  As for the authors case, why ON EARTH are you looking at the test results?  Automate that comparison!

Comment: Sometimes you just need to control the order, to debug which test is interfering with another and how.

Answer (score 254, accepted):

> I think it's quite important feature for JUnit, if author of JUnit doesn't want the order feature, why?

I'm not sure there is a clean way to do this with JUnit, to my knowledge JUnit assumes that all tests can be performed in an arbitrary order. From the FAQ:

> #### [How do I use a test fixture?](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#tests_2)
>
> (...) The ordering of test-method invocations is **not guaranteed**, so testOneItemCollection() might be executed before testEmptyCollection(). (...)

Why is it so? Well, I believe that making tests *order dependent* is a practice that the authors don't want to promote. Tests should be independent, they shouldn't be coupled and violating this **will** make things harder to maintain, will break the ability to run tests individually (obviously), etc.

That being said, if you really want to go in this direction, consider using  TestNG since it supports running tests methods in any arbitrary order natively (and things like specifying that methods depends on groups of methods). Cedric Beust explains how to do this in [order of execution of tests in testng](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2669576/70604).

Comment: I suspect that JUnit4 tests are in fact done in spec order.  It is not guaranteed because that would (1) promote bad practices among testers and would (2) tie JUnit's hands somewhat.

Comment: Either you have two independent tests, or you only have one test and should code as such.

Comment: @JonFreedman, as I understand the question, it's not a case of the tests being interdependent, just of having a spec of things to test and wanting the results to appear in that order.

Comment: I can understand not enforcing order for unit tests, however when using JUnit to write integration tests it would be nice to be able to specify the order that tests are run. E.g. Run the login test first.

Comment: @BrianD. login is probably a "fixture" instead of a test that must run before all the others. I will probably write a BeforeClass that logs in and then write the tests to execute in any order.

Comment: I would probably do login as a Rule so that one field in the class can simultaneously declare the test to login as well as logout. Although this raises a second related question, which is, what if another Rule wants to be logged in before it runs? Now you have some order dependency again.

Comment: The implication "tests should be independent => tests should be ORDER independent" is not true. Consider automated grading of student's homeworks. I want to test their solution for smaller inputs first and for larger inputs later. When the solution is failing for smaller inputs (for time/memory limit), then why should the tests run for larger inputs?

Comment: >>>>> TL;DR and Ressurrecting mode on! -> JUnit is wrong! If I want to run the unit test in a class and assume the first succeeds to test another one (let's say for inclusion and edition of a value) it will allow the last to fail if the failure is actually in the first.

Comment: Note, JUnit does not run them in the order they are defined in the class. I have seen them run in different order for at least JUnit 4.10.

Comment: @Pascal Wouldn't a TestSuite solve this problem? We used them to test databases where the individual tests were independent it also made sense to combine some tests together into a larger scenario, such as (create table/insert data/delete data/drop table). This was before JUnit4, so my apologies if TestSuite has been deprecated or replaced with some newer feature. My question would be whether you would recommend TestSuites at all.

Comment: Junit 4.11 has the feature now - see other answer by Özhan Düz

Comment: Junit是不能按照函数申明的顺序，进行顺序执行的，有违作者的设计本意。如果你非要这么做。那你可以使用TestNG

Answer (score 135):

If you get rid of your existing instance of Junit, and download [JUnit 4.11](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22junit%22%20AND%20a:%22junit%22) or greater in the build path, the following code will execute the test methods in the order of their names, sorted  in ascending order:

```
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void testAcreate() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }
    @Test
    public void testBupdate() {
        System.out.println("second");
    }
    @Test
    public void testCdelete() {
        System.out.println("third");
    }
}
```

Comment: We've actually tried a similar method test_001_login(), for example, but although it mostly works to preserve order, it is not guaranteed- we have several instances per test run where 004, 005, and 006 are run after 007. It makes you say, "WTF!," and run to StackOverflow for answers.

Comment: in my tests: testAcase - worked, test_A_case / testA_case - did not!

Comment: I have tried this annotation parameter "MethodSorters.JVM", e.g. "@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)". From the API: JVM - 
Leaves the test methods in the order returned by the JVM. Works just fine for my what I'm doing (CRUD), runs the test methods in the order they are written in. +1

Comment: This annotation is indeed an answer, but it has the caveat that it is not defined (in Junit 4.12) with `@Inherited` and therefore becomes ineffective on my `AbstractTestCase` parent class.

Comment: I have jUnit 4.12 and this hack does not work

Answer (score 55):

Migration to TestNG seems the best way, but I see no clear solution here for jUnit. Here is most **readable solution / formatting** I found for jUnit:

```
@FixMethodOrder( MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING ) // force name ordering
public class SampleTest {
    @Test
    void stage1_prepareAndTest(){};

    @Test
    void stage2_checkSomething(){};

    @Test
    void stage2_checkSomethingElse(){};

    @Test
    void stage3_thisDependsOnStage2(){};

    @Test
    void callTimeDoesntMatter(){}
}
```

This ensures stage2 methods are called after stage1 ones and before stage3 ones.

P.S. I feel this approach is better that jUnit 5.5 @Order annotation because it provides better notation for reader.

Comment: This approach is nice, but it would be valid to mention that if you have more than 10 tests it wont work fine unless you add a `0` prefix, e.g. `void 
 stage01_prepareAndTest(){ }`

Answer (score 52):

If the order is important, you should make the order yourself.

```
@Test public void test1() { ... }
@Test public void test2() { test1(); ... }
```

In particular, you should list some or all possible order permutations to test, if necessary.

For example,

```
void test1(); 
void test2(); 
void test3(); 


@Test
public void testOrder1() { test1(); test3(); }

@Test(expected = Exception.class)
public void testOrder2() { test2(); test3(); test1(); }

@Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
public void testOrder3() { test3(); test1(); test2(); }
```

Or, a full test of all permutations:

```
@Test
public void testAllOrders() {
    for (Object[] sample: permute(1, 2, 3)) {
        for (Object index: sample) {
            switch (((Integer) index).intValue()) {
                case 1: test1(); break; 
                case 2: test2(); break; 
                case 3: test3(); break; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `permute()` is a simple function which iterates all possible permuations into a Collection of array.

Comment: In the first code block, `test2` runs `test1` _again_. Junit may still run `test2` before `test1`. This is likely not what you intended, and not a valid answer to the question.

Comment: this would share state between tests and @Before would be called only once which is undesired for more complex tests like testing Activities on android

Answer (score 30):

JUnit since 5.5 allows `@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)` on class and `@Order(1)` on test-methods.

JUnit old versions allow test methods run ordering using class annotations:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.DEFAULT)
```

By default test methods are run in alphabetical order. So, to set specific methods order you can name them like:

> a_TestWorkUnit_WithCertainState_ShouldDoSomething
> b_TestWorkUnit_WithCertainState_ShouldDoSomething
> c_TestWorkUnit_WithCertainState_ShouldDoSomething

Or

> _1_TestWorkUnit_WithCertainState_ShouldDoSomething
> _2_TestWorkUnit_WithCertainState_ShouldDoSomething
> _3_TestWorkUnit_WithCertainState_ShouldDoSomething

You can find [examples here](https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-test-order).

Answer (score 25):

**JUnit 5 update (and my opinion)**

> I think it's quite important feature for JUnit, if author of JUnit doesn't want the order feature, why?

By default, unit testing libraries don't try to execute tests in the order that occurs in the source file.

JUnit 5 as JUnit 4 work in that way. Why? Because if the order matters it means that  some tests are coupled between them and that is **undesirable for unit tests**.
So the `@Nested` feature introduced by JUnit 5 follows the same default approach.

**But for integration tests, the order of the test method may matter** since a test method may change the state of the application in a way expected by another test method.
For example when you write an integration test for a e-shop checkout processing, the first test method to be executed is registering a client, the second is adding items in the basket and the last one is doing the checkout. If the test runner doesn't respect that order, the test scenario is flawed and will fail.
So in JUnit 5 (from the 5.4 version) you have all the same the possibility to set the execution order by annotating the test class with [`@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)`](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/5.5.0/api/org/junit/jupiter/api/TestMethodOrder.html) and by specifying the order with `@Order(numericOrderValue)` for the methods which the order matters.

For example :

```
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class) 
class FooTest {

    @Order(3)
    @Test
    void checkoutOrder() {
        System.out.println("checkoutOrder");
    }

    @Order(2)
    @Test
    void addItemsInBasket() {
        System.out.println("addItemsInBasket");
    }

    @Order(1)
    @Test
    void createUserAndLogin() {
        System.out.println("createUserAndLogin");
    }
}
```

Output :

> createUserAndLogin
>
> addItemsInBasket
>
> checkoutOrder

By the way, specifying `@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)` looks like not needed (at least in the 5.4.0 version I tested).

**Side note**
About the question: is JUnit 5 the best choice to write integration tests?  I don't think that it should be the first tool to consider (Cucumber and co may often bring more specific value and features for integration tests) but in some integration test cases, the JUnit framework is enough. So that is a good news that the feature exists.

Comment: @Order doesn't work as expected. It executes the methods in random fashion or in alphanumeric order.

Answer (score 21):

Its one of the main issue which I faced when I worked on Junit and I came up with following solution which works fine for me:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

import org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod;
import org.junit.runners.model.InitializationError;

public class OrderedRunner extends BlockJUnit4ClassRunner {

    public OrderedRunner(Class<?> clazz) throws InitializationError {
        super(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    protected List<FrameworkMethod> computeTestMethods() {
        List<FrameworkMethod> list = super.computeTestMethods();
        List<FrameworkMethod> copy = new ArrayList<FrameworkMethod>(list);
        Collections.sort(copy, new Comparator<FrameworkMethod>() {
        
            @Override
            public int compare(FrameworkMethod f1, FrameworkMethod f2) {
                Order o1 = f1.getAnnotation(Order.class);
                Order o2 = f2.getAnnotation(Order.class);

                if (o1 == null || o2 == null) {
                    return -1;
                }

                return o1.order() - o2.order();
            }
        });
        return copy;
    }
}
```

also create a interface like below:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Order {
    public int order();
}
```

Now suppose you have class A where you have written several test cases like below:

```
@RunWith(OrderRunner.class)
class A {
    @Test
    @Order(order = 1)
    void method() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

So execution will start from method named "method()".
Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The (as yet unreleased) change https://github.com/junit-team/junit/pull/386 introduces a `@SortMethodsWith`. https://github.com/junit-team/junit/pull/293 at least made the order predictable without that (in Java 7 it can be quite random).

Comment: Seems that #386 has been merged in 4.11.

Comment: `@SortMethodsWith` has been renamed to `@FixMethodOrder` and [was released in 4.11](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/blob/main/doc/ReleaseNotes4.11.md#test-execution-order).

Answer (score 7):

Look at a JUnit report.  JUnit is already organized by package.  Each package has (or can have) TestSuite classes, each of which in turn run multiple TestCases.  Each TestCase can have multiple test methods of the form `public void test*()`, each of which will actually become an instance of the TestCase class to which they belong.  Each test method (TestCase instance) has a name and a pass/fail criteria.

What my management requires is the concept of individual **TestStep** items, each of which reports their own pass/fail criteria.  Failure of any test step must not prevent the execution of subsequent test steps.

In the past, test developers in my position organized TestCase classes into packages that correspond to the part(s) of the product under test, created a TestCase class for each test, and made each test method a separate "step" in the test, complete with its own pass/fail criteria in the JUnit output.  Each TestCase is a standalone "test", but the individual methods, or test "steps" within the TestCase, must occur in a specific order.

The TestCase methods were the steps of the TestCase, and test designers got a separate pass/fail criterion per test step.  Now the test steps are jumbled, and the tests (of course) fail.

For example:

```
Class testStateChanges extends TestCase

public void testCreateObjectPlacesTheObjectInStateA()
public void testTransitionToStateBAndValidateStateB()
public void testTransitionToStateCAndValidateStateC()
public void testTryToDeleteObjectinStateCAndValidateObjectStillExists()
public void testTransitionToStateAAndValidateStateA()
public void testDeleteObjectInStateAAndObjectDoesNotExist()
public void cleanupIfAnythingWentWrong()
```

Each test method asserts and reports its own separate pass/fail criteria.
Collapsing this into "one big test method" for the sake of ordering loses the pass/fail criteria granularity of each "step" in the JUnit summary report.  ...and that upsets my managers.  They are currently demanding another alternative.

Can anyone explain how a JUnit with scrambled test method ordering would support separate pass/fail criteria of each sequential test step, as exemplified above and required by my management?

Regardless of the documentation, I see this as a serious regression in the JUnit framework that is making life difficult for lots of test developers.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure I agree, If I want to test 'File Upload' and then test 'Data Inserted by File Upload' why would I not want these to be independent from each other? Perfectly reasonable I think to be able to run them separately rather than having both in a Goliath test case.

Comment: People often get confused between unit test and integration tests. They try to apply best practice for unit tests to integration tests thinking that "they follow the best practice". Unfortunately those are the people who make a lot of noise!

Answer (score 6):

**JUnit 4 update**

As of JUnit 4.13 `@OrderWith`, it is possible to reproduce the JUnit 5 `@Order` annotation. This solution better integrates with JUnit 4 than `@RunWith` a custom  `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner` implementation.

Here's how I could replace method name ordering (`@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`) with an ordering by annotation.

```java
@OrderWith(OrderAnnotation.class)
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    @Order(-1)
    public void runBeforeNotAnnotatedTests() {}

    @Test
    public void notAnnotatedTestHasPriority0() {}

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void thisTestHasPriority1() {}

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    public void thisTestHasPriority2() {}
}
```

```java
/**
 * JUnit 4 equivalent of JUnit 5's {@code org.junit.jupiter.api.Order}
 */
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ ElementType.METHOD })
public @interface Order {
    /**
     * Default order value for elements not explicitly annotated with {@code @Order}.
     *
     * @see Order#value
     */
    int DEFAULT = 0;

    /**
     * The order value for the annotated element.
     * <p>Elements are ordered based on priority where a lower value has greater
     * priority than a higher value. For example, {@link Integer#MAX_VALUE} has
     * the lowest priority.
     *
     * @see #DEFAULT
     */
    int value();
}
```

```java
import org.junit.runner.Description;
import org.junit.runner.manipulation.Ordering;
import org.junit.runner.manipulation.Sorter;

/**
 * Order test methods by their {@link Order} annotation. The lower value has the highest priority.
 * The tests that are not annotated get the default value {@link Order#DEFAULT}.
 */
public class OrderAnnotation extends Sorter implements Ordering.Factory {
    public OrderAnnotation() {
        super(COMPARATOR);
    }

    @Override
    public Ordering create(Context context) {
        return this;
    }

    private static final Comparator<Description> COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparingInt(
            description -> Optional.ofNullable(description.getAnnotation(Order.class))
                                   .map(Order::value)
                                   .orElse(Order.DEFAULT));
}
```

The not annotated tests get a default priority of 0. The order of tests with the same priority is undetermined.

Gist: https://gist.github.com/jcarsique/df98e0bad9e88e8258c4ab34dad3c863

Inspired by:

- [Aman Goel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40211661/515973)
- [Test execution order Wiki by JUnit team](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-execution-order#orderwith-annotation)
- [JUnit 5 source code](https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/blob/main/junit-jupiter-api/src/main/java/org/junit/jupiter/api/MethodOrderer.java)

Answer (score 4):

What you want is perfectly reasonable when test cases are being run as a suite.

Unfortunately no time to give a complete solution right now, but have a look at class:

```
org.junit.runners.Suite
```

Which allows you to call test cases (from any test class) in a specific order.

These might be used to create functional, integration or system tests.

This leaves your unit tests as they are without specific order (as recommended), whether you run them like that or not, and then re-use the tests as part of a bigger picture.

We re-use/inherit the same code for unit, integration and system tests, sometimes data driven, sometimes commit driven, and sometimes run as a suite.

Comment: Have you not had time to complete this answer since 2014? ;)

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, tests should be ideally be independent of execution order. This makes tests less fragile, and allows them to be run independently (many IDEs allow you to select a test method and execute it independently of other tests).

That being said, for integration tests, some people prefer to rely on method ordering.

Starting with JUnit 4.13 you can define your own class to reorder tests by extending [`Ordering`](https://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/manipulation/Ordering.html). See [the JUnit wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-execution-order#orderwith-annotation) for more details. Here's an example using the built-in `Alphanumeric` class to order the tests alphanumerically using the test method name:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.OrderWith;
import org.junit.runner.manipulation.Alphanumeric;

@OrderWith(Alphanumeric.class)
public class TestMethodOrder {

    @Test
    public void testA() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }
    @Test
    public void testB() {
        System.out.println("second");
    }
    @Test
    public void testC() {
        System.out.println("third");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's time to move to **Junit5**.
Here is a sample of what we could get:

```
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
 class OrderedTests {

     @Test
     @Order(1)
     void nullValues() {}

     @Test
     @Order(2)
     void emptyValues() {}

     @Test
     @Order(3)
     void validValues() {}
 }
```

For **Junit4**, copy the logic that you have in several tests in one test method.

Answer (score 2):

For JUnit 4, putting this annotation on the test class solved the problem.

```java
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)
```

Comment: @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM): Leaves the test methods in the order returned by the JVM. This order may vary from run to run.

Comment: @krizajb That's true. In my case, most of the time, the ordering is same as in the source code. And that works very well for me. Only when some tests fail, the failed tests will come first in the next run.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of these piece of codes:
`@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)` OR `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.DEFAULT)` OR `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)`

Before your test class like this:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class BookTest {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

With  JUnit 5.4, you can specify the order :

```
@Test
@Order(2)
public void sendEmailTestGmail() throws MessagingException {
```

you just need to annotate your class

```
@TestMethodOrder(OrderAnnotation.class)
```

https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order

i'm using this in my project and it works very well !

Answer (score 0):

I've read a few answers and agree its not best practice, but the easiest way to order your tests - and the way that JUnit runs tests by default is by alphabetic name ascending.

So just name your tests in the alphabetic order that you want. Also note the test name must begin
with the word test. Just watch out for numbers

test12 will run before test2

so:

testA_MyFirstTest
testC_ThirdTest
testB_ATestThatRunsSecond

Answer (score 0):

Please check out this one: https://github.com/TransparentMarket/junit. It runs the test in the order they are specified (defined within the compiled class file). Also it features a AllTests suite to run tests defined by sub package first. Using the AllTests implementation one can extend the solution in also filtering for properties (we used to use @Fast annotations but those were not published yet).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension to JUnit that can produce the desired behavior: https://github.com/aafuks/aaf-junit

I know that this is against the authors of JUnit philosophy, but when using JUnit in environments that are not strict unit testing (as practiced in Java) this can be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here thinking that my tests weren't run in order, but the truth is that the mess was in my async jobs. When working with concurrency you need to perform concurrency checks between your tests as well.
In my case, jobs and tests share a semaphore, so next tests hang until the running job releases the lock.

I know this is not fully related to this question, but maybe could help targeting the correct issue

Answer (score 0):

**If you want to run test methods in a specific order in JUnit 5, you can use the below code.**

```
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
public class MyClassTest { 

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    public void test1() {}

    @Test
    @Order(2)
    public void test2() {}

}
```