# Selenium junit tests - how do I run tests within a test in sequential order?

Tags: eclipse, testing, selenium, junit, sequential

I am using junit with eclipse to write function tests.

When running an individual test it runs in the order that I have them set within the class.

Eg.

```
testCreateUser
testJoinUserToRoom
testVerify
testDeleteUser
```

However when I run this test as part of a suite, (so in a package) the order is random.

It will for example do the verify, then delete user then joinuserToRoom then Createuser.

My tests within the suite are not dependent on each other. However each individual test within a test is dependent on them being run in the correct order.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't guarantee the order of execution of test **methods** in JUnit.

The order of execution of test **classes** within a suite **is** guaranteed (if you're using [Suite](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/Suite.html)), but the order of execution if the test classes are found by reflection isn't (for instance, if you're running a package in Eclipse, or a set of tests from maven or ant). This may be definable by ant or maven, but it isn't defined by JUnit.

In general, JUnit executes the test methods in the order in which they are defined in the source file, but not all JVMs guarantee this (particulary with JVM 7). If some of the methods are inherited from an abstract base test class, then this may not hold either. (This sounds like your case, but I can't tell from your description).

For more information on this, see my answer to [Has JUnit4 begun supporting ordering of test? Is it intentional?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7845929/has-junit4-begun-supporting-ordering-of-test-is-it-intentional/7846712#7846712).

So what can you do to fix your problem? There are two solutions.

In your original example, you've actually only got one test (verify), but you've got 4 methods, two setup (createUser, joinUserToRoom) and one teardown (deleteUser). So your first option is to better define your test cases, using a [TestRule](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/TestRule.html), in particular [ExternalResource](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/ExternalResource.html). `ExternalResource` allows you to define before/after behaviour for a test, similar to `@Before/@After`. However, the advantage of `ExternalResource` is that you can factor this out of your test.

So, you would create/delete the user in your external resource:

```
public class UsesExternalResource {
     @Rule
     public ExternalResource resource= new ExternalResource() {
         @Override
         protected void before() throws Throwable {
            // create user
         };

         @Override
         protected void after() {
            // destroy user
         };
     };

     @Test
     public void testJoinUserToRoom() {
        // join user to room
        // verify all ok
     }
}
```

For me, this is simpler and easier to understand, and you get independent tests, which is a good thing. This is what I would do, but you will need to refactor your tests a bit. You can also stack these Rules using [RuleChain](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/rules/RuleChain.html).

Your second option, if you really want to introduce dependencies between your test methods, is to look at [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html), in which you can define dependencies from one test to another.

Answer (score 0):

If they have a 'correct' order, then they are not multiple tests, but a single test that you have incorrectly annotated as being multiple independent tests.

Best practise would to rewrite them in approved junit style (setup - act - verify), supported by @Before or @BeforeClass methods that did any required common setup.

Quick workaround would be to have a single @Test-annotated method that called the other test methods in sequence. That becomes something like the preferred alternative if you are using Junit not to do strict unit testing, but something more like scenario-driven systems testing. It's not necessarily the best tool for such use, but it does work perfectly well in some cases.

Then, what you would have so far is have a single test:

```
@Test public void testUserNominalLifeCycle(...
```

which could then, if you are feeling virtuous, be supplemented by extra new tests like

```
@Test public void testUserWhoNeverJoinsARoom(...
```

Comment: Thanks Soru, test's within the package can be run in any order. But the tests within those tests need to be run in the correct order. So it must login as admin create a user and join that user to a room. Then login as that user and run the test. I'm not sure how its possible to run this kind of test without any dependencies...?

Comment: For unit-style testing, you can have an @Before (or @BeforeClass) that creates required users, and a corresponding after-annotated function that cleans them up.