# Scheduling test on server

Tags: java

There are variety of tests, each of them has its frequency. If test starts at t time, it should be also  mandatory started for all t + interval (test frequency) times. Tests are running on the server. Tests start times should be scheduled so that the server load time will be equal  over time. What algorithms can you  suggest?

Comment: Don't know if the algorithm question really is appropriate for Stack Overflow. It looks, however, that you could use a build server (such as Jenkins) to run your tests. In jenkins you can specify when to run the builds.

Comment: What language is your development code is ? If is java, and if you use  continuous integration servers (eg Hudson), you could schedule your tests to run at pre-defined time. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9528581/specifying-order-of-execution-in-junit-test-case