# Selenium Webdriver test cases - Test cases not executing in an order

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium web driver to test my web test cases with maven, But when I am executing they are executed in random order. 
I have tried many examples but all is vain.It's increasing my headache.

Comment: Can you give a little more information, like if you're using junit or some other testing framework?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using some kind of pattern ? Best way would be to configure a test Suite that would run these individual tests ? If you are newbie to writing tests , this should help

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jUnit or any similar framework, then you can not rely on methods being executed in any particular order - at least not easily. See for example [How to run test methods in specific order in JUnit4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4) for more information. Up to Java 6 it used to work that way, but it was never guaranteed. Java 7 breaks it.

I try to not rely on execution order at all. This makes it easier to run individual tests and to restructure them. If there is common setup, then I try to factor it out into setup methods (@Before/@BeforeClass in jUnit 4).

Answer (score 0):

you can make a `priority` for each test case. so that for each test case the min priority means that it will be executed first.

For example:

```
@Test(priority = 0)
public void test1() {

   // your code

}

@Test(priority = 1)
public void test2() {

   // your code

}
```

So, `test1` will be executed first, then `test2` will be executed after it.