# Order of evaluation of multiple @Test annotation inside a class in Junit

Tags: junit, junit4, junit3

Can anyone tell me what is the order of evaluation of @Test annotation in Junit when you have multiple @Test Annotation?
I was trying with the following example but didnot find any specific order.You may consider the following example to explain your answer.

```
package test_Cases;

import org.junit.Test;

public class First_test_case {
    @Test
public void apsTest(){
    System.out.println("THIS IS FIRST TEST CAES.");
    //selenium code
}
@Test
public void appletestTest(){
    System.out.println("THIS IS second TEST CAES.");
    //selenium code
}
@Test
public void aboutestTest(){
    System.out.println("THIS IS third TEST CAES.");
    //selenium code
}

@Test
public void dtestTest(){
    System.out.println("THIS IS fourth TEST CAES.");
    //selenium code
}@Test
public void etestTest(){
    System.out.println("THIS IS fifth TEST CAES.");
    //selenium code
}@Test
public void ftestTest(){
    System.out.println("THIS IS sixth TEST CAES.");
    //selenium code
}


}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run test methods in specific order in JUnit4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4)

Comment: That's not implemented in JUnit (because the author thinks you should not depend on the order of your tests). If you absolutely need it, either use a third-party test runner or switch to another framework such as TestNG. (edit: I just saw that Junit 4.11 provides a solution! See the linked-to question for details).

Comment: @JoachimSauer is right, being "independent" is one of the properties of good tests. You can read here http://www.cavdar.net/2008/10/25/properties-of-good-tests-a-trip/ a description of the others as well

Answer (score 5):

Using `@FixMethodOrder` JUnit annotation we can achieve ordered execution of the junit tests

**Note:** We need to use JUnit 4.11 or later versions to get this option

**Example Code Snippet:**

```java
import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

// Test execution order : ascending order of method names
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class OrderedJUnitTest {
    @Test
    public void second() {
        System.out.println("Inside second test");
    }

    @Test
    public void first() {
        System.out.println("Inside first test");
    }

    @Test
    public void third() {
        System.out.println("Inside third test");
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> Inside first test
>   Inside second test
>   Inside third test

Similarly we can use `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.DEFAULT)` and `@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.JVM)` as well which will order the test execution.

Visit https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Test-execution-order to get more insight on this.