# How to organize tests sequence in ant or jenkins

Tags: ant, jenkins, selenium-webdriver

I use selenium WebDriver with junit, ant and jenkins. 
I set up jenkins to use ant build.xml to run my tests. But currently I run only one tests. In build.xml I set variable which is used in each test. So to run test in Jenkins I set in Targets:

```
build MyTest1 -Dvariable="value"
```

I want to run all tests in sequence one after another. I try this:

```
build MyTest1 -Dvariable="value" MyTest2 -Dvariable="value"
```

But 2  tests began run in browser at the same time. How can I organize needed sequence. Maybe there are some ways to do it in build.xml? I guess I can create target, in which call targets which runs tests, but how set my variable in that case? I'm new to ant so please advice me solution.

I need to clarify - my tests are independent, I won't run them in some stable sequence. The problem is that tests are running in parallel in browser. I need to run first test and only after it finish - run second test.

Comment: I'm sorry, junit, it is just typo

Comment: You can set the ant property to the value which you are passing from command line to a variable ( & note it is immutable ) & have your dependency chain created with your targets : MyTest1 , MyTest2 ... ?

Comment: There is a pretty decent answer in [this thread][1] also.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4

Answer (score 1):

First of all, tests should have little dependencies. In your case, your tests depend on a global variable - try to get rid of it. Use a "configuration" object that you can modify from tests in a safe way and which your application code then uses to configure itself.

Which reduces the problem above to "how do I collect a number of tests" to which the answer is: [Use a test suite](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_suite_test.htm):

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
   MyTest1.class,
   MyTest2.class
})
public class JunitTestSuite {   
}
```