# Running multiple tests using RestAssured serially

Tags: spring-boot, rest-assured

I have a Spring Boot application which is capable of running Integration tests using Rest Assured.

There is a single test class which has multiple test cases. I wish to run the test cases serially as given in the class.

```
public class ItemControllerTest{
    @Before
    public void setUp(){
     ...
    }

    @Test
    public void test1(){
     ...
    }

    @Test
    public void test2(){
     ...
    }
}
```

When I run integration test,it seems test2 is getting executed before test1.

But I want them to run in the order they are written

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with spring-boot, but if you are using Junit to run your tests, then you can run them serially by adding the following annotation above your class:

```
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ItemControllerTest{

// tests will run in order here

}
```