# Wrong order of running JUnit's methods in IDEA

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I have a problem with Idea 14 and JUnit. I can't run @BeforeClass and @AfterClass methods in proper order (before all test and after all test). Every time order is different. I tried to reinstall IDEA, delete all settings but nothing works. Please help. This is example of my test code:

```
package com.rent.test;

import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class testnewTest {
    static int num;
    static int num1;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void OnceExecutedBeforeAll() {
        System.out.println("@BeforeClass: onceExecutedBeforeAll");
        num = 15;
        num1 = 16;
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void after() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("End");
    }

    @Test
    public void testLogin() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test");
        assertEquals(15, num);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetOrdersDate() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test2");
        assertEquals(16, num1);
    }
}
```

This is output:

```
 test2
 @BeforeClass: onceExecutedBeforeAll
 test
 End
```

Comment: Works fine in my IDEA 14.1.3 with JUnit 4.12. Which versions are you using?

Comment: In junit the order of execution  is not defined, check the link below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4

Comment: @RafaelGuillen: That's more for the individual tests.  Order isn't guaranteed but it's deterministic.  This concerns the `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`.

Comment: Version of IDEA: 14.1.4

Answer (score 3):

What you're likely observing is the fact that the output is not always going to be synchronous in the terminal.  The test *themselves* are running in the correct sequence.

If they weren't, then you would have failures in `test2` given that it would have appeared that your `@BeforeClass` method fired *afterwards*.

Comment: Sometimes test tries to run tests before @Beforclass methods end and test failure because of lack of proper context.