# How to create a .zip file from two .doc file?

Tags: java, zip, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I want to write a unit test to test creating .zip file from two .doc files. BU I take an error: Error creating zip file: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\file1.txt (The system cannot find the file specified)

My code is here:

```
@Test
public void testIsZipped() {

    String actualValue1 = "D:/file1.txt";
    String actualValue2 = "D:/file2.txt";

    String zipFile = "D:/file.zip";

    String[] srcFiles = { actualValue1, actualValue2 };

    try {

        // create byte buffer

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFile);
        zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        for (int i = 0; i < srcFiles.length; i++) {

            File srcFile = new File(srcFiles[i]);

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcFile);

            // begin writing a new ZIP entry, positions the stream to the
            // start of the entry data

            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(srcFile.getName()));

            int length;

            while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            zos.closeEntry();

            // close the InputStream

            fis.close();
        }

        // close the ZipOutputStream

        zos.close();

    }

    catch (IOException ioe) {

        System.out.println("Error creating zip file: " + ioe);
    }

    String result = zos.toString();

    assertEquals("D:/file.zip", result);
}
```

Can I get name of zip file from zos to test, How to understand to pass the test? Can anybody help me to solve this error? Thank you.

Comment: My guess is that the file is either not there or the path is wrong (Windows uses `\` to separate path, which you have to escape.

Comment: Does `D:\file1.txt` exist? Do you have read rights to it? Possibly consider trying `D:\\file1.txt`

Comment: I created file1.txt and file2.txt files in D directory. Now there is no error but I did not pass the test. I tried these to define directory : "D:\\file1.txt", "D:\file1.txt" and "D:/file1.txt".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are your files created in a previous test method? If yes consider that junit tests do not execute in the order you defined your test methods, have a look at this:
[How to run test methods in specific order in JUnit4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4)

Second, you could add a debugging line:

```
File srcFile = new File(srcFiles[i]);
System.out.append(srcFile+ ": " + srcFile.exists() + " " + srcFile.canRead());
```

After you solve the exception you will run into this problem, the test will fail:

```
String result = zos.toString();

assertEquals("D:/file.zip", result);
```

zos.toString() will return something like: "java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream@1ae369b7" which will not be equal to "D:/file.zip".

```
String zipFile = "D:/file.zip";
ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));
System.out.println(zos.toString());
```