# How to run junit suite in parallel using maven surefire plugin

Tags: java, maven, junit, maven-surefire-plugin

I have a testsuite say JunitTest1 and JunitTest2 as below,

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses({ 
    com.sample.test1.class,
    com.sample.test2.class,
    com.sample.test3.class,
})

public class JunitTest1 {

}

@RunWith(Suite.class)
    @SuiteClasses({ 
        com.sample.xxx1.class,
        com.sample.xxx2.class,
        com.sample.xxx3.class,
    })

    public class JunitTest2 {

    }
```

I want to run both the testsuite in parallel but the test class inside the testsuite should run in the specified order. I have added the below plugin in maven pom.xml,

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <parallel>suites</parallel>
                    <threadCount>2</threadCount>
                    <!-- <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                    <reuseForks>true</reuseForks> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I have followed this link - http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html

I have tried all the possible combination for parallel tag like **methods, classes, both, suites, suitesAndClasses, suitesAndMethods, classesAndMethods, all** but nothing seems to solve my problem. The test suite are still running in sequential if i use **suites** and for other options the test classes in test suite are running in random order

Is there anything i am doing it wrong? can anyone please guide me to solve this issue ?

Comment: Why do you need to run the suite in a specific order?  This sounds like bad test, it should be possible to run them in any order

Comment: @robjwilkins The test class are dependent. For example, an id will be generated in testcase1 and that needs to be used in subsequent test cases.

Comment: So all the test class in test suite should run in the given order

Comment: You shouldn't use test suites (simply remove them)...let maven-surefire-plugin do it's work..

Comment: The reason to use test suite is that i want to run the test classes in same order as i mentioned in my question

Answer (score 0):

junit tests should be independent of one-another.  junit does not provide a means to order tests to prevent you from writing tests which are dependent on other tests.

There are other SO threads on this topic:

[How to run test methods in order with Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36066767/how-to-run-test-methods-in-order-with-junit)

and

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4

Comment: I am able to run the test cases in order. I am looking for a solution to run the test class in the test suite to run in same order during parallel execution. For my above example, I want to run JunitTest1 and JunitTest2 in parallel and during the parallel execution, JunitTest1 should run test1, test2 and test3 and JunitTest2 should run in xxx1, xxx2 and xxx3 . I am not able to execute in this order during parallel execution via surefire plugin