# Default Execution Order of Test Classes in JUnit 4

Tags: java, junit4, order-of-execution, test-class

Pretty much the title says it all. Note that the question is order of "classes" not the test methods inside them. Per answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53848489/8847871), the default execution order of test methods within a class can be configured using `@FixMethodOrder` and the default is computed using the hash of function names.