# Is there a way to execute junit test in written order ?

Tags: junit, junit4

Usually I usethe annotation **@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)** and my tests start by test001_nametest1, test002_nametest2, ..

With this method adding a test between existing test is problematic (because you have to rename all test after).

Is there a way to execute all junit test in the **written** order ?

Comment: The question you want to be asking your is "why?".  What's your reasoning for doing this?

Comment: In my design, I have dependencies between tests. Some creates data in database that are consumed by others so the order is important.

Comment: Check out the options posted in the similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4

Comment: Generally your tests should be independent of each other.

Comment: Instead of relying on order, have each of your tests ensure they have the right data independently.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run test methods in specific order in JUnit4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4)