# Run JUnit5 tests in strict order

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I want to use JUnit5 for tests but looks like @ScenarioTest is not yet implemented.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

How I can run tests in strict order?

Comment: to my knowledge,not, neither should you have to. a test is supposed to be completely boxed in, meaning they always should have the correct same result, no matter what order they run in, or dependent on whether or not other tests are run

Comment: [Related answer on why you don't want to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3693706/3788176).

Answer (score 2):

Not yet, but with 5.4, perhaps: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/13