# How to run controller test classes in order with spring integration test

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-test, mockmvc

Running controller test classes in order.

I have this test classes below.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class UserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void findAll() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/user").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
        RestResponse restResponse = mapper.readValue(response.getContentAsString(), RestResponse.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(restResponse.getHttpStatus().name(), HttpStatus.OK.name() );
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class ProductControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void findAll() throws Exception {
        MvcResult result = mockMvc
                .perform(get("/api/product").contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk()).andReturn();

        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
        RestResponse restResponse = mapper.readValue(response.getContentAsString(), RestResponse.class);
        Assert.assertEquals(restResponse.getHttpStatus().name(), HttpStatus.OK.name() );
    }

}
```

I want to run this controller test classes in order. For example, first UserControllerTest runs after that ProductControllerTest.

How can i do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run test methods in specific order in JUnit4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4)

Answer (score 2):

If you have Junit 5 as dependency you can control complete control of the **order of the methods** but within the test class itself by using `@TestMethodOrder`.

Regarding the **order of the test classes** themselves there is not much control available. Maven Failsafe docs say about the `<runOrder>` configuration:

> Supported values are "alphabetical", "reversealphabetical", "random",
>   "hourly" (alphabetical on even hours, reverse alphabetical on odd
>   hours), "failedfirst", "balanced" and "filesystem".

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
      <runOrder>alphabetical</runOrder>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>integration-test</goal>         
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```