# Run random order test class in Java project with maven

Tags: java, maven, testing, random

I have a java project and I have to launch the methods of a test class in random order. Is there a way to do that with Maven?

I tried with **surefire** and **runOrder**, but the configuration works with a test suite, in fact it launches the classes in random order but not the methods within them.

Comment: Tests should be as reproducible as possible. Running them in random order makes this more difficult.

Comment: You should use JUnit Jupiter which can execute test method explicitly in random order  https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-test-execution-order

Comment: @khmarbaise The project has junit4, so I can't use Jupiter.

Comment: @JFMeier I somewhat disagree - running tests in random order might reveal hidden dependencies between tests

Comment: Is using `MethodSorters.JVM` per [The JUnit Wiki](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Test-execution-order) good enough for your purpose?

Comment: @GyroGearless Investigating this is certainly useful. I just fear that I change something, run the tests again, get a red test and don't know whether this comes from my test or some hidden dependency.

Comment: Junit 4 does not support explicitly run in random order JUnit Jupiter does...

Comment: actually, the order of the test methods is not guaranteed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4