# how to run junit parameterized tests in order of parameters declared

Tags: junit4, paramterized

I am writing a junit parameterized test, and I have the following parameters for example:
"A",
"B",
"C".
Everytime I run the test, the parameter's order is always different and I want it to always run in the order I defined them.

Is there a way?

I ve searched online, but I could not find any info about it...

Comment: Please provide any [mcve]

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko  I have a set with 57 parameters and I want to create some data only once before the tests to run cause I dont want to overwhelm the pipeline.
I want to do something like:
if (parameter.equals("A") {...create data}

But not always the first test that gets executed is with parameter == "A"

Comment: You could take a look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693626/how-to-run-test-methods-in-specific-order-in-junit4

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using sort() on collection inside method that is marked with @Parameterized annotation