# How to find test that affects execution of other tests?

Tags: java, gradle, junit

I'm currently struggling with a pretty hard problem: I'm working on a project that has around 8 thousands of unit tests (that take 15 minutes to execute on pretty strong machine) and test that are currently failing don't fail when run on they or own (or when run with other tests that failed), so I guess there is some test that passes but leaves some mess behind.

I'm currently trying to run those tests with tests from specific packages, using gradle:

```
test {
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching 'some.package.*'
        includeTestsMatching '*Test1'
        includeTestsMatching '*Test2'
    }
}
```

However there are some things I don't know how to control, like execution order of test classes (if someone has an idea how to change order that would also help me).

Perhaps someone already knows some nice process of finding tests affecting other tests?

Comment: a unit test should never affect the functioning or outcome of another unit test

Comment: @Stultuske ofcourse :) but I can't fix it, if I can't find it :/

Comment: Use [bisection method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection_method), I'm afraid. If the whole test always fails, then test execution order is likely the same every time. Alternatively, if you can track the point in time when the test began to fail, that might be a key to solving this.

Comment: Point is... How I can be sure that order remains the same? Perhaps test filter affects order, since so far I wasn't able to reproduce problem on smaller sample...

Comment: "How can I be sure that order remains the same" ... basically, you can't.

Comment: "How can I be sure that order remains the same" ...and nor should you want to. If a given test depends upon a previous test leaving things in a particular (but unknown) state, how can you reason about the result of that test simply by looking at its code? What is the test case *actually* telling you about the correct functioning of the code? You should put in the work to remove the ordering dependency.

Comment: "some nice process of finding tests affecting other tests" Ruthless removal of sources of mutable global state.

Comment: @AndyTurner damn. How can I explain it simpler? It's broken and I know it - no need to tell me that tests shouldn't depend on each other, however I can't help it if someone else messed up few months or years ago. As you said I can only hope to fix it, but on big project it may be almost impossible to review and understand hundreds or thousands of test classes and how they can affect the rest... With dozens of libraries it may be hard to find common stuff (and what if it is a bug deep in some library that causes it?).

Comment: @AndyTurner don't get me wrong. But you basically said: 'you code is broken you need to fix it'. It doesn't help me much - I already know it's broken, I already know it shouldn't behave this way, problem I have is the scale of codebase.

Comment: Would this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19552700/3788176 (obviously you'd need to expand it a bit for "thousands")

Comment: @AndyTurner no, I want to control the order only to find broken test classes (because if I'm out of luck I won't able to reproduce problem without running tests in specific order). And if it is possible I would also introduce some mechanisms to prevent that kind of situation in future (like alternating between one test order and reverse order).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106350/discussion-between-korda-and-andy-turner).

Comment: Maybe suitable assertions could be added to each test class' "before" and "after", to ensure that environment is "clean"? Of course feasibility of this depends on what kind of environment we are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming junit tests, then:

1. define a [test suite](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Aggregating-tests-in-suites) that specifies the ordering of test classes
2. ensure you are using junit 4.11 or later to get a [deterministic method order](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/doc/ReleaseNotes4.11.md#test-execution-order)
3. run only the test suite from gradle (or just directly from your ide)
4. adjust the ordering by editing the suite until you reproduce the problem