# Automatically execute Selenium TestNG script using java

Tags: java, selenium, automation, execution

Im working on an application where client sends me the selenium files and i have to execute those files in Selenium webdriver. I dont want to use Selenium RC. I did a small research and all i could found is recommendation to use Selenium RC. Please help. A link or code will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

TestNG by itself provides such functionality - execution model. You use TestNG with [Silk4J](http://www.borland.com/products/silktest/read/) to create sequenced regression tests (assuming this is waht is required from you). All of the tests execution can be in a specific order - and some tests trigger a 'skip all remaining tests' when a super-critical error occurs.

I'm sure that you'll find these TestNG resources helpful:

- [How_to_execute_tests](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_executing_tests.htm)
- [Execution_procedure](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/testng/testng_execution_procedure.htm)
- [Execution_Order_of_tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669576/order-of-execution-of-tests-in-testng)

Comment: i didnt mean automation automatic. I was asking about how to execute it at a point. Say 5 sec after the application starts the code will automatically run the testNG scripts. Thanks for stopping by.