# Does using Method Interceptor in TestNG skips the test on fail or Execute it even if any fails?

Tags: java, testing, testng

I would like to know if using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28124123/5595366) skips the following test methods or marks it as fails. I know if priority is used the following methods will be run and will not be dependent. I wanna know how method interceptor orders the methods....

Thanks...

Comment: Have you tried it out?

Comment: Nope, I'm new to testNG and testing. So i want to know how this works. So that i can understand much better. I will try it once i know enough about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're asking is: When using an `IMethodInterceptor` to order tests, will a failed test method cause subsequent tests to fail? No. **Ordering tests using `IMethodInterceptor` does not create dependencies.**

This is pretty easy to test yourself. I definitely recommend trying it out to see how it behaves in different scenarios.