# Fails to execute second @Test method in TestNG

Tags: testng

Fails to hit method2() for following code snippet

```
public class project 
{
    static WebDriver driver;

    @Test()
    public void method1()
    {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\52013597\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("url");
    }

    @Test()
    public void method2()
        {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-panel\"]/div[2]/form/div[3]/input")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-panel\"]/div[2]/form/div[3]/input")).sendKeys("TOYVA30U5VC");
        }
}
```

> [RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 6.14.2
>   Starting ChromeDriver 2.38.551601 (edb21f07fc70e9027c746edd3201443e011a61ed) on port 10902
>   Only local connections are allowed.
>   Aug 08, 2018 8:13:37 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
>   INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>   PASSED: method1
>   FAILED: method2
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Framework1.project.method2(project.java:24)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
>       at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>       at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
>       at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>       at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
>       at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
>       at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
>       at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)

===============================================
    Default test

## Tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

===============================================
Default suite

## Total tests run: 2, Failures: 1, Skips: 0

Comment: driver object is not available in test method 2 as it is created locally in method 1, you should not create new driver object, instead of that use static object.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `driver` object, either add to method2:

```
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Or move this statement from method1 to class level.

Answer (score 0):

You have define Webdriver at multiple place, Instead you have to initialize object value to driver in @Test method.

```
public class project 
{
static WebDriver driver;

@Test()
public void method1()
{
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\52013597\\Desktop\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("url");
}

@Test()
public void method2()
    {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-panel\"]/div[2]/form/div[3]/input")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"login-panel\"]/div[2]/form/div[3]/input")).sendKeys("TOYVA30U5VC");
    }
}
```

Or You can define it in Class level or Separate method without @Test annotation if you want to reuse it in another class.

Comment: order isn't guaranteed,so if `method2` will be execute before `method1` `driver` will be null and it won't work

Comment: @user7294900 But TestNG executes Test as according to alphabetic order, Isn't  it so?

Comment: No according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669576/order-of-execution-of-tests-in-testng

Comment: No, It may be for earlier version. Look at this my demo http://prntscr.com/kghiae

Comment: Anyway it's a bad practice assuming order of unit test that should/can be executed as a **unit**

Comment: Yes, Its OP's choice how to handle it. We can give direction only.