# Classes in Testng file seem to get initialized together

Tags: java, inheritance, testng

I have two classes inheriting from a `MyTestData` class which gets testdata from excel depending on the parameter passed to it.

```
public class A1 extends MyTestData {

    public A1() {
        super("A1");
    }

    @Test
    //Methods
```

--

```
public class A2 extends MyTestData {

    public A2() {
        super("A2");
    }

    @Test
    //Methods
```

--

```
public class MyTestData {

    public MyTestData(String test) {

        System.out.println("test data parameter is " + test);
        switch (test) {
        case "A1":
            A1_data();
            break;
        case "A2":
            A2_data();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void A1_data() {
        //Fetch data from excel
    }

    private void A2_data() {
        //Fetch data from excel
    }
```

I have these two classes in a testng.xml file

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite1">
    <test name="Test A1">
     <classes>
       <class name="mypackage.A1"/>
     </classes>
   </test>

  <test name="Test A2">
     <classes>
       <class name="mypackage.A2"/>
     </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

But when I run the xml file I get this output on console as soon as execution starts:

```
test data parameter is A1
test data parameter is A2
```

And the test A1 runs with data of A2. Why is this happening and how can I prevent this? I want A2 to start after A1 has completed execution.

Comment: This may help for ordering of A1,A2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669576/order-of-execution-of-tests-in-testng

Comment: I guess this for tests within a class, my case has different classes.